# Swift Package Manager - add the package dependency to your Package.swift for react native

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, swift-package-manager

To integrate exampleSDK using Swift Package Manager, add the package dependency to your Package.swift

```
dependencies: [
.package(url: "https://github.com/example-sdk", branch: "main")
]
```

I need to integrate the iOS SDK to react native project. As per the instructions I need to add the dependencies to Package.swift.

I am not able to find the package. swift in react native project

Where I need to create the Package.swift in react native project?

---

Steps I had done to integrate the SDK to ios.

I have added the below pod to project podfile.

```
pod 'exampleSDK', :git => 'https://github.com/example-sdk'
```

Installed the pod file successfully.

---

after running the project in Xcode. showing an error

```
Error: Framework not found exampleSDK
```

---

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to add the package dependency without writing any code by using Xcode.

By following this [link](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devb83d64851).

- Your dependency SDK should be present in the git.